# PHP pass url to index.php

Tags: php, .htaccess

This should be really simple, but I want to be able to use the url as a variable like the php frameworks do.

```
mywebsite.com/hello-world
```

I want my index.php to see "hello-world" as a variable and I want index.php to load. Is this done through php or do I have to use a htaccess file?

Many php frameworks use urls to send a message to the index file... for example...

```
mysite.com/controller/view
```

How would I route these myself via php?

A little help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 2 steps:

1. Rewrite the url using an `.htaccess` file (on linux). You need to make sure all requests go to your php file so you will need to rewrite all requests to non-existing files and folders to your php file;
2. In your php file you analyze the url (using for example `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`) and take action depending on its contents.

For step 1. you could use something like:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ your_file.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]
```

And then in your php file in step 2. you have the requested url in `$_GET['url']`.

**Edit:**

If you want to rewrite only certain sub-directories, you could also use a rule like:

```
RewriteRule ^sub/dir/to/rewrite/(.*)$ your_file.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Some details:

- `^(.*)$` captures everything (all characters) between the start `^` and the end `$`. They are captured using the parenthesis so that you can use them in the query string like `$1`. In the edited example, only the section after `..../rewrite/` gets captured;
- The options between `[ ... ]` mean that it is the `L` Last rule to process and `QSA` that the original query string is also added to the new url. That means that if your url is `/hello-world?some_var=4` that the `some_var` variable gets appended to the rewritten url: `your_file.php?url=hello-world&some_var=4`.

Comment: Is there a way to have it not go to the root directory without specifying the root directory but have it rely on where the .htaccess file is? I hope that made sense... I have my index.php file located in a sub directory.

Comment: @Joseph I think you have to specify the root directory with `RewriteBase`; I don't think you can tell Apache to set `RewriteBase` dynamically based on the location of the .htaccess file.

Comment: @Joseph See my edit. But you can either analyze the query string or the original url (like I mentioned at the top), there is not much difference.

Comment: @MattBrowne Ok, another quick question... What is the point of "^(.*)$" verses the way that you and the other answers have written it. Also what does "[L,QSA]" do?

Comment: @Joseph `^(.*)$` allows the URL to be set as a GET parameter (where @jeroen has `url=$1`), which can be convenient, but either way works. Since you're dealing with subdirectories you're probably better off with @jeroen's version. Not sure about `[L,QSA]`; I've been copying that from others to be honest ;)

Comment: For the sake of future web searchers: if it doesn't work or you get a 500 internal server error, it may be because you need to configure Apache to enable .htaccess files and allow the RewriteEngine directive to be used.

Answer (score 1):

This sort of rerouting must be done on the webserver level, either in the Apache config files for your server or (more likely) through an `.htaccess` file.

This is the `.htaccess` file I use on my own site to do this sort of re-routing:

```
# Allow any files or directories that exist to be displayed directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

#Route everything else through index.php
RewriteRule .* index.php/?$0 [PT,L]
```

Then in `index.php` I look up the URLs in my database to pull the page content:

```
if(isset($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) and strlen($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) > 1)
    $requested_url = substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 1);
else
    $requested_url = 'home';
```

Answer (score 1):

What you want to achieve is called the "Front Controller" pattern. It's usually done with the use of Apache's `mod_rewrite`. Without URL rewriting you can still do something similar, but your URLs would look like this:

`mysite.com/index.php/controller/view`

Instead of:
`mysite.com/controller/view`
as you want.

Here's a minimal .htaccess file to do the URL rewriting:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

Then you parse the URL from `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` but remember to strip off any GET parameters at the end when determining the view name.

I personally wanted something like this recently without a full-fledged framework so I used this micro-framework just to do the routing, and it worked very nicely:

http://www.slimframework.com/

Then you can write your own controller class and set up the routing; here's the code I used:

```
$app = new \Slim\Slim();

$app->map('/:controller(/:action)', 'dispatchControllerAction')
    ->via('GET', 'POST');

function dispatchControllerAction($controllerName, $action='index') {
    //multi-word controllers and actions should be hyphen-separated in the URL
    $controllerClass = 'Controllers\\'.ucfirst(camelize($controllerName, '-'));
    $controller = new $controllerClass;
    $controller->execute(camelize($action, '-'));
}

/**
 * Adapted from the Kohana_Inflector::camelize function (from the Kohana framework)
 * Added the $altSeparator parameter
 * 
 * Makes a phrase camel case. Spaces and underscores will be removed.
 *
 *     $str = Inflector::camelize('mother cat');     // "motherCat"
 *     $str = Inflector::camelize('kittens in bed'); // "kittensInBed"
 *
 * @param   string  $str    phrase to camelize
 * @param   string  $altSeparator  Alternate separator to be parsed in addition to spaces. Defaults to an underscore.
 *      If your string is hyphen-separated (rather than space- or underscore-separated), set this to a hyphen
 * @return  string
 */
function camelize($str, $altSeparator='_')
{
    $str = 'x'.strtolower(trim($str));
    $str = ucwords(preg_replace('/[\s'.$altSeparator.']+/', ' ', $str));

    return substr(str_replace(' ', '', $str), 1);
}
```