# How do I find the 20th regex match group?

Tags: regex, .htaccess

I am doing a rewriterule inside of my .htacess folder in one of my htdocs folders.
The rewriterule looks something like this:

```
RewriteRule ^index/(blah)/(blah2)/(blah3)..../(blah20)
```

^^^The above code looks like bad practice--don't worry about that.
Anyways, I heard before that ${20} was the correct way to access the 20th match group in regex, but even though in regex101 my 20th match group is matching blah20, whenever I print out the 20th capture group, I just get ${20}.
Why is this? Am I correctly accessing two digit match groups?

Edit--real rewriterule:

```
RewriteRule ^a/([\d]*)/(b/([\d]{2}:[\d]{2}:[\d]{2})/?)?(c/(\w*)/?)?(d/([\w]
{6})/?)?(e/([\w]{6})/?)?(f/([\w]{6})/?)?(g/([\w]{6})/?)?(h/([\w]{6})/?)?
(i/([\w]{6})/?)?(j/([\w]{6})/?)?(k/([\w]{6})/?)?(l/([\w]{6})/?)?(m/([\w]
{6})/?)? /index.php?a=$1&b=$3&c=$5&d=$7&e=$9&f=${11}&g=${13}&h=${15}&i=${17}&
j=${19}&k=${21}&l=${23}&m=${25} [L]
```

Comment: `whenever I print out the 20th capture group` - How are you printing it?

Comment: RewriteRule ^index/(blah)/(blah2)/(blah3)..../(blah20)                   
/index.php?id=$1&param2=$2&param3=$3...   I then print out the url in index.php from the $_REQUEST global variable. Since param20 =$20, I then know what the 20th capture group is.

Comment: See my answer below. Anything beyond `$9` is not supported.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use back-reference number greater than 9 [as per official mod_rewrite documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html).

From Manual:

> **RewriteRule back-references:** These are back-references of the form `$N (0 <= N <= 9)`. `$1` to `$9` provide access to the grouped parts (in parentheses) of the pattern, from the RewriteRule which is subject to the current set of `RewriteCond` conditions. `$0` provides access to the whole string matched by that pattern.

If you are dealing with so many back-references then it is better to pass full URI after `index/` to `index.php` and use explode inside the php code:

```
RewriteRule ^index/(.+)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: How would I break up my RewriteRule into multiple rewrite rules @anubhava? If you can tell me that, I will gladly accept your answer. Thanks, George Chen

Comment: Can be done but if you are dealing with so many back-references then it is better to pass full URI after `index/` to `index.php` and use `explode` inside the php code.

Comment: Ok got it, I knew that something like this would be better: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17246714/php-pass-url-to-index-php; can you explain how I would go about doing the more inconvenient way though--ie multiple rewrite rules? I am really curious for an intuitive explanation @anubhava.

Answer (score 0):

For example like [this](https://regex101.com/r/fd8avG/2):

```
RewriteRule \^index(?:\/\w+){5}\/(blah6)
```

Will match 6th folder in the url.

Comment: That's not exactly what I meant. I meant how I would find the 20th match group using $# notation. You can access the 1st match group in .htaccess using $1. How would you access the 20th match group in .htaccess? I heard you do it like so... ${20}, but that kind of notation isn't working for me as of now.